# What is Personal category?

Tags: gmail

I found category `Personal` while creating filter. But this category is not visible to any other places (settings, left bar).

Why and how to use this category?

[image]

Comment: That is odd. What are the other options in that menu? I haven't seen any announcement that Google has added any category options to "Social", "Updates", "Forums", or "Promotions". Perhaps this is an A/B test?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...I see it too.

It appears to be a new name/label for the "Primary" category, and my experiments with a filter bear that out. I don't know if this is a partially completed change, an experiment, leakage from G-Suite Gmail, or what, but it appears harmless.

I'll wager that it'll go back to being "Primary" very soon.

Answer (score 0):

This *WAS* to allow you to sort your emails with 'labels' and NOT with 'categories'.  (Categories are your tabs along the top; Labels are down the left.)  Say you have a high volume or low priority source. You used to be able to create a label, select the 'Personal' category and all mail would go to that label without being listed in any of your tabs.  This was great in removing pollution in your category because you wouldn't see it in *ANY* tabs. You check your label when you want. Less mental energy reading email.  But Gmail in their infinite wisdom decided to remove this feature.  Now every email **MUST** have a category and you **MUST** see it somewhere.